# How can we approximate the integrand?

Tags: calculus

How can we approximate the integrand of $$\int_0^\infty \exp\left({-(x-a)^2\over 2a}\right)$$ so that the integral is approximated by $$\sqrt{2\pi a}$$?

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SE. You might want to give some more context to your question to get better answers. Feel free to look around the site to see how questions are formulated to achieve most useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $a<0$ is necessary, otherwise the integral diverges. Now, $$u=\frac{x-a}{\sqrt{2(-a)}},$$ so that you have $du=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2(-a)}}$. Now integrate $$\sqrt{2(-a)}\int_{\sqrt{-a/2}}^\infty \exp(-u^2)\,du.$$

Comment: Which equals $+\infty$.

Comment: @julien: You are correct. I've edited it now; thanks.

Comment: I think this is wrong.  What is the value of $u$ at the lower integration limit?  I don't think it is $0$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: You are correct. I think it's been edited (?) correctly now. I was actually in the process when you commented. Either way, it seems a poor answer to me.

Comment: Thank you, Clayton. I have stupidly left out a minus sign -- edited.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is positive, the integral diverges.  If $a$ is negative, the peak is to the left of zero and the integral will be less than $\sqrt {\frac {\pi a}2}$, which is what it would be if the integrand were $\exp(\frac {x^2}a)$

Comment: Thank you, Ross. I have left out a minus sign :/ Does it work now?

Comment: Now it diverges is $a$ is negative.  If $a$ is large and positive, the integral will be close to $\sqrt 2 {\pi a}$ because the peak will shift to the left.  The standard deviation is $\sqrt {\frac a2}$, so the peak is $\sqrt {2a}$ standard deviations above zero.  The tail below $0$ will get small as $a$ gets large.  You can use the error function to integrate this, but that is just giving it a name.  You can look up approximations to it based on the number of standard deviations.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Clayton's corrected answer, the integral is

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi a}{2}} \mathrm{erfc}{\left (\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}} \right )}$$

where $\mathrm{erfc}$ is the complement of the error function.  For small values of $a$, this takes the value, roughly of $\sqrt{\frac{\pi a}{2}} - a$